# Division by defined constant in Obj-C does not work

Tags: objective-c, c-preprocessor, modulo, nsrange

If I write

```
#define ANOTHER_CONSTANT 200
#define MYDIVISOR 1000/ANOTHER_CONSTANT
```

and then a method

```
- (void)result {
    NSRange range = [@"--BB-------A----" rangeOfString:@"A" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
    int rest = range.location % MYDIVISOR;
    NSLog(@"Rest is %i", rest);
}
```

the output is always that rest is 0, no matter where the A occurs. I have solved it by storing the MYDIVISOR into an intermediate integer variable, but I would like to know why it does not work with the predefined constant. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

This is because you did not put parentheses around your `MYDIVISOR` definition:

```
#define MYDIVISOR (1000/ANOTHER_CONSTANT)
```

Without parentheses, the code will look like this after the substitution by the preprocessor:

```
int rest = range.location % 1000 / ANOTHER_CONSTANT;
```

Because `%` and `/` have the same priority and are applied left-to-right, the compiler would generate the code that obtains a remainder of the division by `1000`, and then quickly divide the result by `200`, which is certainly not what you'd expect.

In general, it is a good idea to always put parentheses around your entire macro. In case of function-like macros with parameters, it is also a good idea to parenthesize each parameter as well.

Comment: There is also a potential problem if the integer constants don't divide evenly.